# POE Connection Failure

Tags: linux, ethernet

I have 2 POE ports which are on different NICs. When I connect them together the ports' Ethernet does not come up. In other words, the associated "port status" register of those ports should turn to "1" upon the connection; though, in this case the register stays "0".

When I connect the same POE port to another non-POE (normal Ethernet), the register turns to "1".

I wonder if there is any constraint in connecting two POE ports together. Any help would be highly appreciated?

**Additional Info:** I have to connect these 2 POEs together for a testing purpose.

Comment: Is the non-POE on the same server, or is it on a switch or router or other external device?

Comment: They are on 2 different switches; but the switch module are same and switch configuration are also same.